# check white space of a string at the begin

Tags: php, string

Is there any way to check the white space at the begin of a string ? I have tried strpos but look like it doesn't work. I use `$_POST['text']="    hi"` and it output `ok` in my code. It suppose to be an error.

```
<form action="#" method="POST">
    text <input type='text' name='text'/><br/>
    <input type='submit' value='submit'/>
    </form>

    <?php


    if(isset($_POST['text']) && !empty($_POST['text']))
    {
        if(strpos($_POST['text'],' '))
        {
            echo 'found white space';
        }
        else
        {
            echo 'not found';
        }
    }
    else
    {
        echo 'none';
    }
```

Comment: Did you at least read [the manual page for `strpos`](http://us.php.net/strpos)? It has examples of this specific problem...

Comment: @user3228228  Why did you unaccept my answer? Is there anything I can improve on it?

Answer (score 1):

`strpos()` will search through the whole string. At the end and in the middle.

Also, you should always use `!== false` resp. `=== false` when using with `strpos()`.

You can use this for your problem:

```
if (ctype_space($_POST['text'][0])) {

}
```

`ctype_space()` is better than `$_POST['text'][0] == ' '`, since it also checks for tabs or null characters etc.

PS: If you simply want to remove whitespaces, use `trim()` . If you just want to remove at the left, you can use `ltrim()` .

Answer (score 0):

With `strpos` you find all spaces in your string (or better, first space in your string, not directly first character). Use `substr` for testing first character.

```
if (!empty($_POST['text'])) {      
    if (substr($_POST['text'], 0, 1) == ' ') {
        echo 'First char is space';
    } else {
        echo 'First char isn\'t space';
    }
} else {
    echo 'String is empty.';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if(ltrim($str) == $str)
{
    echo 'No Space';
}
else
{
    echo 'There are space';
}
```

This code will check if there are space at the begin of a string.

Comment: Like a lot of things in PHP, this blows up with purely numeric strings: http://3v4l.org/LbbgD

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer for you. The answer is quite simple you have to just use false and true statement to check weather it has space or not. I have edited your answer please check it.

```
<form action="#" method="POST">
    text <input type='text' name='text'/><br/>
    <input type='submit' value='submit'/>
    </form>

    <?php


    if(isset($_POST['text']) && !empty($_POST['text']))
    {
$sx=strpos($_POST['text'],' ');
        if($sx==true)
        {
            echo 'found white space';
        }
        else
        {
            echo 'not found';
        }
    }
    else
    {
        echo 'none';
    }
```

Tell if it works